# How to find the unicode character of a particular tamil word in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find the length of particular tamil word in the mysql database. I used the command 
SELECT LENGTH(phrase)as Len FROM table WHERE Condition;

But i did not get the correct length..

What is the command that i can use to find the length?

Answer (score 0):

With `char_length`. Manual link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length